# Pivoting without aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to take away the Aggregate function from a Pivot query.

I have a Problem with this query because if i have employees with the same birthday only the first one appears.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT lastname +' '+ firstname as name, Birthdate, 
        CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1930 AND 1939 THEN 1930
        WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1940 AND 1949 THEN 1940
        WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1950 AND 1959 THEN 1950
        WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1960 AND 1969 THEN 1960
        WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1970 AND 1979 THEN 1970
        WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1980 AND 1989 THEN 1980
        WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1990 AND 1999 THEN 1990
        WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009 THEN 2000
        ELSE DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) END as [BDate] FROM ADR_Address 

) as s
PIVOT
(
    MAX(name)
    FOR [BDate] IN ([1930],[1940],[1950],[1960],[1970],[1980],[1990],[2000])
)AS pvt
WHERE Birthdate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Birthdate
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data? Also a tip: if you use `(DATEPART(yyyy, Birthdate)/10)*10)` you don't need that entire `case` statement, and you won't need to add to the `CASE` when new birthdays come in scope.

Comment: What result are you expecting to get?

Comment: @user2210516 Y U NO UPVOTE OR ACCEPT ANSWERS?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code right, you could add another separator to the pivoted rows, for example a row number. So instead of Birthdays you will have Birthdays+Original row number on pivoted rows.

This way you can technically show all the names but this kind of pivot is still weird:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT lastname +' '+ firstname as name, Birthdate, 
    CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1930 AND 1939 THEN 1930
    WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1940 AND 1949 THEN 1940
    WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1950 AND 1959 THEN 1950
    WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1960 AND 1969 THEN 1960
    WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1970 AND 1979 THEN 1970
    WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1980 AND 1989 THEN 1980
    WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 1990 AND 1999 THEN 1990
    WHEN DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009 THEN 2000
    ELSE DATEPART(yyyy,Birthdate) END as [BDate]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY lastname +' '+ firstname) AS rn FROM ADR_Address 
) as s
PIVOT
(
    MAX(name)
    FOR [BDate] IN ([1930],[1940],[1950],[1960],[1970],[1980],[1990],[2000])
)AS pvt
WHERE Birthdate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Birthdate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set nocount on
--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499843/pivoting-without-aggregate-function
/*Logic in brief
  --------------
  1) Work out the maximum number of rows to be output based on the largest number of rows in across birth decade/birth year 
  2) Create a dummy record for the number of rows calculated in 1)
  3) Split by birth decade/birth year by allocating a counter(joinbylink) reset to 1 for every birth decade/birth year
  4) Self join all the birth decade/birth year groups driven by the dummy record
*/


declare @currentdecade int = 2000       --Dynmically control if listed by decade of birth or year of birth 
declare @dynamicsql varchar(200)
declare @dynamicsql2 varchar(4000)

if  (exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = 'joins'))
begin
    drop table joins
end
if  (exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = 'emp'))
begin
    drop table emp
end
if  (exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = 'emp2'))
begin
    drop table emp2
end

create  table joins                     --Table to hold join statements for dynamic sql
(joinstatement nchar(200))

create table emp                        --employee table
(
Name nchar(10),
birthdate  datetime,
birthdecade int
)
insert into emp (name,birthdate)
values  ('jsmith',cast('1930/01/01' as datetime)),
         ('jsmith',cast('1931/02/01' as datetime)),
         ('abc',cast('1940/01/01' as datetime)),
         ('def',cast('1950/01/01' as datetime)),
         ('ghi',cast('1954/01/01' as datetime)),
         ('jkl',cast('1950/01/01' as datetime)),
         ('mno',cast('2000/01/01' as datetime)),
         ('pqr',cast('2005/01/01' as datetime))

create table emp2                       --employee table with a self join link
(
Name nchar(10),
birthdate  datetime,
birthdecade int,
joinbylink int
)

update emp                              --Work out birthdecade and decide if discrete year of birth should be maintained
set birthdecade = 
    case 
    when year(birthdate)/10 * 10 = @currentdecade then year(birthdate)
    else year(birthdate)/10 * 10
    end 

declare @maxrows int = 0 
declare @loopcnt int = 1
/*Find the max rows needed based on the maximum number of employes in a birth decade or birth year*/
SELECT  @MAXROWS =  MAXROWS FROM
(
SELECT  TOP 1 birthdecade,COUNT(*) MAXROWS FROM emp GROUP BY birthdecade order by count(*) desc
) S
/*Populate a table with maxrows of dummy records*/
while @loopcnt <= @maxrows 
begin
insert into emp (NAME,birthdate,birthdecade) VALUES ('Dummy',cast('1900/01/01' as smalldatetime),1900)
set @loopcnt = @loopcnt + 1
end


insert into emp2        --create a work table with a join by link
select  * ,row_number() over (partition by birthdecade order by birthdecade) from emp 


/*Generate join statements for use by dynamic sql*/
insert into joins
select 'select emp' + cast(birthdecade as nchar(4)) +'.name as ' + char(39) + cast(birthdecade as nchar(4)) + char(39)
FROM emp  
where   birthdecade = 1900
group by birthdecade order by birthdecade asc

insert into joins
select ',emp' + cast(birthdecade as nchar(4)) +'.name as ' + char(39) + cast(birthdecade as nchar(4)) + char(39)
FROM emp  
where   birthdecade <> 1900
group by birthdecade order by birthdecade asc

insert into joins
select 'From emp2 as emp1900'

insert into joins
select 'Left join emp2 as emp' +  cast(birthdecade as nchar(4)) + ' on emp' + cast(birthdecade as nchar(4)) + '.joinbylink = emp1900.joinbylink and emp' + cast(birthdecade as nchar(4)) + '.birthdecade = ' + cast(birthdecade as nchar(4)) 
FROM emp  
where   birthdecade <> 1900
group by birthdecade order by birthdecade asc

insert into joins
select 'where emp1900.birthdecade = 1900'

/*for debug                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
select  a.joinbylink, a.name, 
        b.joinbylink, b.name '1930',
        c.joinbylink, c.name '1940',
        d.joinbylink, d.name '1950',
        e.joinbylink, e.name '2000',
        f.joinbylink, f.name '2005'
from    emp2 a
left join   emp2 b on b.joinbylink = a.joinbylink and b.birthdecade = 1930
left join   emp2 c on c.joinbylink = a.joinbylink and c.birthdecade = 1940
left join   emp2 d on d.joinbylink = a.joinbylink and d.birthdecade = 1950
left join   emp2 e on e.joinbylink = a.joinbylink and e.birthdecade = 2000
left join   emp2 f on f.joinbylink = a.joinbylink and f.birthdecade = 2005
where   a.birthdecade = 1900
*/

/*Build a dynamic sql statement from join table and execute it*/

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT  joinstatement
FROM    joins

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH next FROM db_cursor INTO @dynamicsql
set @dynamicsql2 = rtrim(@dynamicsql) 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dynamicsql 
       if @@fetch_status = 0 
        begin
            set @dynamicsql2 = @dynamicsql2 + ' ' + rtrim(@dynamicsql)
        end
END   

exec (@dynamicsql2)

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this part of your query:

```
SELECT  lastname +' '+ firstname as name,
        Birthdate,
        ...
```

On this:

```
SELECT  lastname +' '+ firstname as name,
        Birthdate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Birthdate) as rn,
        ...
```